# Poor SQL Server performance on virtual machine after system upgrade

Tags: sql-server, database, performance, virtual-machine

I'm managing middle sized company database. Recently we have massive system upgrade and switched to virtual machine environment. After deployment, we are having performance issues, Apparently SQL Server on the upgraded system works slower than the old configuration.

Here are the configurations:

- Old Server: SQL Server 2008, 10gb Ram, Intel Xeon E5420 x2 (Physical Machine) runs on Windows Server 2008
- New Server: SQL Server 2014, 64gb Ram, Intel E5 2660 x4 (virtual machine) runs on Windows Server 2012

Very basic IO performance comparison follows as:

new server:

[image: new server]

old server:

[image: old server]

Even with the most basic operation:

```
select * from table
```

from most used tables runs more amount of time to retrieve result. Also stored procedures run slower.

Example:

- new server: 01:39 minute, 3285365 rows
- old server: 01:00 minute, 3339738 rows

I have no idea what could cause this problem. Any help will be appreciated.

Edit:
Both servers has same sql configuration
tempdb and datadb is seperated

Comment: Could be a thousand things but only you can figure out the bottleneck here. Either way, this question doesn't really belong on Stackoverflow, probably get better answers on superuser.com.

Comment: As others have said, it could be a million things: are disk configurations the same (tempdb on separate drive, etc) are SQL Server settings similar, are stats updated and indexes defragged, is there fragmentation at the os file level of the mdb files. If the old system is still up and running, you can compare query plans for the same stored procedure to see if there is a difference. So, fire up the profiler, and real time acitvity monitor, and look for bottlenecks and other things that can degrade performance.

Comment: Actually i myself is not server admin but software specialist. why i'm managing db is quite different story but i need to find out bottleneck what i know right now is

sql settings are quite similar(although i made changes due to having more ram) , all indexes rebuilded. Only thing is tempdb and datadb is on same drive. I will separate these guys and update my post

Answer (score 1):

This probably isn't what you want to hear, but VMs are always slower than physical servers, because of the overhead of implementing the VM. Also the 2660 has MUCH less L2 cache than the old processor.

I'm not sure what to tell you except to make sure that the VM for the SQL Server,  has as much RAM and cores allocated to it as you can spare, and that SQL Server is configured to actually use them.

Also, disk I/O is a big deal. Are the drives and controllers for both systems similar?

VMWare has a whitepaper on the subject, so at least you're not alone. 8-)

http://www.vmware.com/files/pdf/solutions/SQL_Server_on_VMware-Best_Practices_Guide.pdf

Comment: I accept performance drop due to virtualization still, considering better io read/write performance and much more ram, very basic operation like (select *) should be run in less time. (also old system multiple active databases, new one is not)